# How to find unique elements in matrix (per individual cells) and the number of their occurences?

Tags: r, matrix, unique

I would like to get all unique elements in a dataframe and know how many times they occur over the matrix, think of something like this:

[image: example]

I'd want a matrix indicating "11" occurs 1 time etc.

`sort(unique(c(matrix)))` is how far I got.

As this is more of a gimmick to a combinatorial problem, is a matrix the best solution to this anyway?

Thank you for any help for a beginner !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can directly use `table` to get the frequency of all the `unique` elements in the `matrix`

```
table(matrix)
```